# Fastest serialize data format form PHP reading

Tags: php, serialization

I have a PHP frontend and a C++ backend, and I need to be able to send groups of names to the frontend. What serialized format would be the most efficient/fastest for the PHP to read?

Example data

```
group1:
  name1 3923
  name2 9879
  name3 8944
group2:
  name5 9823
group3: 
  name9 9822
  name1 4894
```

What would be the fastest for PHP to read?

- XML
- JSON
- YAML
- Protocol Buffer
- Comma/Space Delimited our own system
- Anything else? other?

Comment: For a few kb of data, pretty much any format you choose will likely parse in under 1 ms -- it's not terribly likely that this will be a major bottleneck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP's own serialized format will probably be the fastest. [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) is the function PHP uses to convert this data back to its own types. [This post](http://objectmix.com/php/362009-specification-serialize.html#post1335166) has various links to other languages' implementations of PHP's serialized format, I'm sure you could convert one of those easily.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the easiest, didn't know PHP's own serialization was this simple.

Answer (score 2):

I've used PHP's serialize() and unserialize() on large text files, and it performed miserably (that was a couple of years ago - maybe it's better now). Anyway, I devised a little trick to overcome this, it simply involves generating a PHP array declaration from the data you're exporting straight into a text file, e.g.:

```
<?php
$groups = array('groups' => array( array('jeff' => 2343,
                                         'tom'  => 8477),
                                   array('baal' => 2873,
                                         'scorpio'  => 3210),
                                   array('jeff' => 2343,
                                         'tom'  => 8477)
                                 )
                            )
               );
?>
```

...and then unserializing it by simply calling:

```
include 'groups.php';//makes $groups available
```

Worked nicely back then.

Comment: This is also one of the few circumstances where using eval() is advisable. SOLR's "php" return type returns a similarly formatted string, which you're supposed to eval()

Comment: eval() can be used, and does the job, but why is it advisable to use it over the technique above (not to be argumentative :) ? I used the above method for processing huge numbers of very large text files.

Answer (score 1):

JSON would be pretty easy using [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/json_decode). I'm not sure about speed, but unless you plan on transferring megabytes of this data between the systems it should be irrelevant which one you go with.

Answer (score 0):

As Paolo pointed out you can use json_decode which is very fast.  On the C++ backend these are some of your options ( taken directly from the [json.org](http://json.org) website ):

C++:

- [TinyJSON](http://blog.beef.de/2008/01/04/tinyjson/).
- [jsoncpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/).
- [zoolib](http://zoolib.cvs.sourceforge.net/zoolib/zoolib/src_other/misc/ZUtil_JSON.cpp).
- [Jaula](http://morongo.homelinux.net/jaula/).
- [JOST](http://ddsbench.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ddsbench/trunk/jost/).
- [JSON Spirit](http://www.codeproject.com/cpp/JSON_Spirit.asp).
- [CAJUN](http://cajun-jsonapi.sourceforge.net/).