# Receive varying variable inputs from PHP into c++

Tags: php, c++, variables, call

I have a program that needs to be sent the following variables:

`Bool` `int` `string` `vector<int>` `vector<string>`

This will come from a `PHP` call as I've looked into [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279003/execute-c-program-with-php-script) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789095/run-c-script-in-php).

Looking at **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)** about `(int argc, char** argv[])`, I know that you can pass various arguments to a program that it needs so to run, but these are all in the form of a [**Character Sequence**](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/).

**So my question is:** If it is possible, how do you go about sending across multiple varying variables in a `PHP` call to a `C++` program?

**EDIT** (Question continued) ...and what would the function call look like?

Is it as simple as not using the `(int argc, char** argv[])` and just doing:

```
int main(bool var1, int var2, std::vector<std::string> var3, std::string var4)
{
...
}
```

Because that seems to make `(int argc, char** argv[])` a tad redundant?

Comment: You can make PHP execute the C++ program as a new process, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6796640). If you want to pass complex arguments, you might want to serialise the arguments in some way. A more complex approach would be to compile the C++ program as a library and load it using something like [`dl`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php), although I'm just guessing, as I have no experience with that.

Comment: `exec()` did look the way to go, but using `exec()` to pass commands, serialised or not, would I set up the function with `(int argc, char** argv[])` or `(bool var1, int var2, std::vector<std::string> var3, std::string var4)`?

Comment: you **always** have to use `(int argc, char** argv[])`

Comment: @m.s. But how can you send across integers, bools, vectors etc to a Character Sequence?

Comment: I already wrote that in my answer below: You must **serialize** your data into character sequence.

Comment: Ohhh, thanks for the clarification. But in my c++ code, I can't assign `char**` to `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: you don't assign it like this. I updated my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute your C++ program in PHP using `exec`:

```
exec("./your_program.exe $parameters", $output);
```

This will pass the contents of `$parameters` as a command line argument to your C++ program. Within `main(int argc, char** argv)`, you can then access this data through `argc` and `argv`.

In order to pass multiple variables at once, you should use some kind of [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). This will convert the contents of your variables into one single string which you can then pass again as a command line argument.
You just have to make sure that the C++ side knows how to unserialize this string into the correct variables / datatypes again.

There is a multitude of possibilities, ranging from inventing your own format (don't do this) to using one of the established ones (do this).

Formats like JSON, XML, [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/), etc. come to mind. You could even implement something using [PHP's own `serialize`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866643/678093) method.

---

To make things more clear, let's **assume** that you want to pass this data from PHP to C++:

```
$var1 = false;
$var2 = 123;
$var3 = array("some","string","data");
$var4 = "anotherstring";
```

let's further assume you have a PHP function `my_serialize()` which converts  `array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4)` into the fictional serialization format `false|123|<some,string,data>|anotherstring`:

```
$serialized_data = my_serialize(array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4));
// $serialized_data  == "false|123|<some,string,data>|anotherstring"

// invoke your program and pass the data
exec("./your_program.exe '$serialized_data'", $output);
```

Within your program, the serialized data is now within `argv[1]`.
You would now need a function `my_deserialize()` which parses the input data and converts them into the respective data format.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
    MyData data = my_deserialize(argv[1]);
    std::cout << data.var4 << std::endl; // outputs "another string"
}
```

Use one of the serialization methods I listed above and you don't have to care about the implementational details of `my_serialize` and `my_deserialize`.